# Check if user exists in Active Directory from client side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a ASP.NET page for creating AD user objects. I am using JQuery for client side validation (to check if user name already exists).
I found some script on Google which returns user properties if user is found in active directory (I will convert this to return bool).

However, if you run this script (below) outside of Visual Studio by directly double clicking ScriptFile.js it works perfectly but when you try the same through visual studio it gives `object undefined` error at `var objRootDSE = GetObject('LDAP://RootDSE');`

Here is the JavaScript function code:

```
function Search(search) {
    var arrSearchResult = [];
    var objRootDSE = GetObject('LDAP://RootDSE');
    var strDomain = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext");
    strAttrib = "samaccountname"; 
    objConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
    objConnection.Open("ADs Provider");
    objCommand = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection;
    var Dom = "LDAP://" + strDomain;
    var arrAttrib = strAttrib.split(",");
    objCommand.CommandText = "Select '" + strAttrib + "' From '" + Dom + "' WHERE objectCategory = 'user' AND objectClass='user' AND samaccountname='" + search + "' ORDER BY samaccountname ASC";
    try {
        objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute();
        objRecordSet.Movefirst;
        while (!(objRecordSet.EoF)) {
            var locarray = new Array();
            for (var y = 0; y < arrAttrib.length; y++) {
                locarray.push(objRecordSet.Fields(y).value);
            }
            arrSearchResult.push(locarray); objRecordSet.MoveNext;
        }
        return arrSearchResult;
    }
    catch (e)
    { alert(e.message); }
}
```

Please suggest how to make this work in visual studio or some other way to check if user exists in AD **from client side**.

Comment: is the client in the AD?

Comment: Yes. in the same domain as this page/app

Comment: were you able to get around this? If so can you please post the code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the solution for that :-(